# MySQL not accepting apostrophes

Tags: mysql, webdna

I've been trying to find a solution for this problem I'm having with my MySQL database not accepting apostrophes. Now before you tell me about escaping the special character or using the mysql_real_escape_string command, PLEASE NOTE, I am NOT using PHP. We have a server running with WebDNA on it (not sure if many of you have heard about it). So no PHP magic will work here, or rather, I would like to NOT use any PHP magic since this is a project for a class of mine. What I want to know is how do I set up my database to accept special characters like the apostrophe? NO PHP SOLUTIONS PLEASE. I want to use the WebDNA code, NOT PHP.

Comment: Escaping the input is language-agnostic.  Use a backslash to escape a single quote `\'` or two single quotes to escape a single one `''`.  But knowing nothing about WebDNA, does it not have its own escaping methods in its MySQL API?

Comment: That's definitely something I didn't think about. I'll look into it and see if they do.